# Retain file extension in a simple while loop (one line)

Tags: bash, file-format, batch-rename

I have a simple string that will rename all jpeg files in a folder sequentially:

`ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "pic-$n.jpg"; done`

But I have a folder with many different file types. Is there a simple string or variable I can replace the `.jpg` with to retain the file extensions? Or does it have to be a full script now? I'd like to keep it to a one liner if possible.

**Examples**

Say I have a folder like this:

```
a long hash name.mp4
another name.m4v
video.mov
another name.mp4
```

and so on. I want to rename the files like the following so that they look more organized and don't have too many characters, like so:

```
vid-1.mp4
vid-2.m4v
vid-3.mov
vid-4.mp4
```

If I were to use `ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "vid-$n"; done`, then I wouldn't have file extensions. I want to retain the file extensions because it makes it easier sometimes to open them.

**I am mainly wondering if there's a global variable in bash to define file extensions**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give one or two examples - I suspect you're looking for parameter expansions like `"${f%.*}"` and `"${f##*.}"` but it's hard to tell from your description

Comment: And also please show us an example of your file names before renaming and what you want after renaming. Parsing `ls` this way is rarely a good idea.

Comment: example added to my original post

Comment: @steeldriver I was messing with `"${f%.*}"` and `"${f##*.}"` but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in the above one-liner. I am mainly wondering if there's a global variable in bash to define file extensions

Comment: @DealTime444 well the `%.*` in `${f%.*}` matches the shortest "dot extension" - so in that sense, it's "global"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a loop here, just use `rename`:

```
$ ls
'a bad name.png'   asdlha.gif   askd.png  'a worse'$'\n''name.jpg'   kasdjh.jpg

$ rename -n 's/.*(\..+)/"pic-" . ++$a . "$1"/se' *
a bad name.png -> pic0.png
asdlha.gif -> pic1.gif
askd.png -> pic2.png
a worse
name.jpg -> pic3.jpg
kasdjh.jpg -> pic4.jpg
```

If that looks right, re-run without the `-n` to actually rename.

**Explanation:**

The `rename` command is a perl script that can run perl code to rename files. Here, we are using the substitution operator (`s/old/new/`) with a couple of special options:

- The `/s` makes the substitution operator treat its input as a single line, allowing `.` to match newline characters. We need this to handle file names with newlines, as I have in the example above.
- The `/e` lets us evaluate the right hand side (`s/left/right/`) as a perl expression. The expression `"pic-" . ++$a . "$1"` means "the string `pic-`, then the value of the variable `$a` incremented by one, and then whatever was matched inside the parentheses on the left hand side". In our case, the extension.

Next, the regular expression used (`.*(\..+)`) means "zero or more characters (`.*`) until the last `.` (`\.` matches a literal `.`), then one or more characters (`.+`). Because the last `\..+` is in parentheses, that makes what was matched (the extension) available as `$1` on the right hand side.

After running the command above without the `-n`, I was left with:

```
$ rename  's/.*(\..+)/"pic-" . ++$a . "$1"/se' *
terdon@oregano foo $ ls
pic-1.png  pic-2.gif  pic-3.png  pic-4.jpg  pic-5.jpg
```

---

Alternatively, you can do this in the shell with something like:

```
i=1; for file in *; do 
  ext="${file##*.}"; 
  mv -- "$file" pic-$((i++))."$ext"; 
done
```

Here, we loop over all files (and directories, if you don't want to rename directories be careful), saving each as `$file`. Then, we get the extension with `${file##*.}`. The `${variable##pattern}` format will remove the longest match for `pattern` from the variable `$variable`. By using `${file##*.}` we remove everything until the last `.`, leaving only the extension which we save as `$ext`.

Next, the `mv` command will rename `$file` to `pic-`, plus the value of the variable `$i`, which we initialize with `i=1`, incremented by one, followed by a `.` and the extension.

Like the `rename` solution above, this too can handle arbitrary file names:

```
$ ls
'a bad name.png'   asdlha.gif   askd.png  'a worse'$'\n''name.jpg'   kasdjh.jpg
$ i=1; for file in *; do 
  ext="${file##*.}"; 
  mv -- "$file" pic-$((i++))."$ext"; 
done
$ ls
pic-1.png  pic-2.gif  pic-3.png  pic-4.jpg  pic-5.jpg
```

Comment: When I run that rename command I get this: `Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at line 1`

Comment: @DealTime444 argh yes, sorry. Ubuntu has a different version fo `rename` than I'm used to. Try the updated command (just change `$i` to `$a` a variable that is already globally defined in perl).

Comment: `rename 's/.*(\..+)/"pic-" . ++$a . "$1"/se' *` works perfectly, but I am left wondering if there's a globally defined variable in bash for file extensions that I could have added to my original command

Comment: No, there isn't. That has nothing to do with bash anyway, it is a perl variable. And in any case, no, bash  has no special thing for extensions. Remember that extensions in Linux are irrelevant.  With very, very few exceptions, such as the `gzip` command, nobody cares about extensions. An image named `foo.boing` can be a png just fine. So there aren't many tools designed to do things with extensions since extensions are optional.

Comment: Understood, it's just that sometimes certain software gets confused if you have the wrong file extension. It also helps when I have default applications set for certain file types. Anyway, I think the rename command answers my question. I asked for a one-liner and that's what you gave me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically need the files to be named arithmetically in *version sort* order (as with `ls -v`) then I'd suggest something like

```
printf '%s\0' *.* | sort -zV | {
  local n=1
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
    echo mv -nv -- "$f" "pic-$((++n)).${f##*.}"
  done
}
```

or, if you want to zero-pad the new names (which makes subsequent sorting easier), perhaps

```
printf '%s\0' *.* | sort -zV | { 
  local n=1
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
    printf -v p 'pic-%03d.%s' $((++n)) "${f##*.}"
    echo mv -nv -- "$f" "$p"
  done
}
```

Remove the `echo` once you have confirmed that the right files will be processed in the desired order. If you don't care about readability you can of course write these as "one liners" if you wish, ex.

```
printf '%s\0' *.* | sort -zV | { local n=1; while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do printf -v p 'pic-%03d.%s' $((++n)) "${f##*.}"; echo mv -nv -- "$f" "$p"; done; }
```